# SPO: User with hyphen in name not showing up in People Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, people-search, debugging

I'm in SharePoint Online. If I search for a user under Everything, then she shows up at the top under "People named .." and clicking the link takes me to her profile. If I go to the People tab and search for her, nothing comes back. She has a user profile, and an active AD account. The only thing I can think of is maybe it's her hyphenated last name. I searched around and didn't see anything about People crawl messing up with hyphens, but I'm not sure what else to look at. It's not a matter of escaping the hyphen in people search either because searching just on her first name still returns nothing.

Anyone have any ideas or where I can look to start debugging this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's working now and it was quite a ride. Turns out on the web part that started this all and on the People search page, there is an additional search query filter for EmployeeType = company. This property is populated in her AD account, but for some reason didn't sync over to her SP profile. I manually populated it, and now she is showing up although her pic doesn't show up in the results, but it's there when you click on her profile. That's an issue for another day I guess.